# He has nothing my car today

Tags: grammar

*He has__my car today.*

A. nothing

B. the

C. a

D. an

This is a question from some English test. The correct answer is A. The Explanation is as follows:  "Exceptions when using definite articles". I am really confused. "Nothing" is a definite article? Can you please explain to me how it is meant?

Comment: **Nothing** here means *none of the other options*. Q. "Which word is best inserted in the gap?" A. "Nothing – none of the others are correct." No article is required, whether definite or indefinite. The grammatically correct sentence is "He has my car today." The test says "Exceptions" and the possessive **my** takes the place of an article. Without that, the sentence would be "He has the car today".

Comment: I suspect A means literally nothing, not the word “nothing”.

Comment: ... and I used the definite article because it seems to be a *particular* car (mine) that is being discussed.

Comment: That is a VERY confusing question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question's list of answer choices is poorly thought out and unclear. What it *means* to say is that the answer is not any of the other answers, and that there should not be anything in the blank. Instead it makes it seem as though the word "nothing" should be put in the blank. What they really should have done was something like this:

> He has__my car today.
>
> A. the
>
> B. a
>
> C. an
>
> D. none of the above